# c++ vs2010 increase stack size

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using vs2010 c++ to process images.

My image is an array of 1920 by 1200.

I can't even declare :

```
unsigned short frame [1920*1200];
```

Due to stack overflow.

How can I increase stack size ?

Comment: compile with /F option?

Comment: Do you really need to increase the stack size? Using a `vector` or an `array` wouldn't kill you.

Comment: Jon,
Thanks for your comment. That is the right solution.
(For my solution I prefer to use a global variable which also not caused a stack overflow).

Comment: @jon what if i want to have an array like int arr[1000000], then what i have to do?

Comment: @bhawin: Just allocate the array on the heap.

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio, you can increase the stack size this way

**Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> Stack Reserve Size**