# Memory requirement: N-point FFT (getting error)

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, out-of-memory, fft

I am trying to do FFT on a data using an FFT library. Attached here is also the code.

The problem is when I try to do FFT of size NX> 2048 (eg. 4096) it gives me error  0xC00000FD: Stack overflow. 
I have seen people posting result doing FFT of around 2^12 and 2^15 points DFT. My question is how should I be able to compute a N point FFT with N>2048.

The signal I am using is just for testing the code. The signal in actual problem will be received in realtime from hardware.

I am using Visual Studio 2010. System Specs (Core i7, RAM : 16GB)

```
// Raw Data Generation
#define TABLE_SIZE 1000
#define TWO_PI (3.14159 * 2.0)
#define CYCLES 20
#define NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES (TABLE_SIZE*CYCLES)

// FFT Values 
#define NX 2048// NX-point DFT
// Sine Generator Function - Real Samples
void sin_func(double *sample_ptr)
{ 
double phaseIncrement = TWO_PI/TABLE_SIZE;
double currentPhase = 0.0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < CYCLES*TABLE_SIZE; i ++){
    *sample_ptr = sin(currentPhase);
    sample_ptr = sample_ptr + 1;
    currentPhase += phaseIncrement;}
}

void main()
{   
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES*sizeof(double);
    const int FFT_OUT_SIZE = sizeof(fftw_complex)*(NX/2+1);

// Initialization 
double rawdata_in[NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES];
fftw_complex fft_out[FFT_OUT_SIZE];    // Sizeof(fftw_complex) = 16
fftw_complex temp[FFT_OUT_SIZE];
double datacheck_out[NUMBER_OF_SAMPLES];

// Creating fft plan
fftw_plan plan;   
plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(NX, rawdata_in , fft_out,  FFTW_MEASURE);


// Initializing Input Array
sin_func(&rawdata_in[0]);

fftw_execute(plan);

// Doing Inverse Transform
fftw_plan plan2;
plan2 = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(NX, temp, datacheck_out, NULL);

memcpy(temp, fft_out, sizeof(fftw_complex)*FFT_OUT_SIZE);
fftw_execute(plan2);

fftw_destroy_plan(plan2);
fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the stack size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case of `N == 4096` the size of your stack allocations look like:

```
const int FFT_OUT_SIZE = 32784;

double rawdata_in[20000];       // 8 * 20000 = 160 kb
fftw_complex fft_out[32784];    // 32784 * 16 = 525 kb
fftw_complex temp[32784];       // = 525 kb
double datacheck_out[20000];    // = 160 kb
                                // Total = 1370 kb
```

It appears the default stack size in VS 2010 is 1MB so this results in a stack overflow. One way of getting around this is to change the stack size in the project options (Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> Stack Reserve Size, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831295/c-vs2010-increase-stack-size)). Another way would be to use dynamic memory allocation like:

```
fftw_complex* fft_out = new fftw_complex[FFT_OUT_SIZE];
   //...use the pointer
delete[] fft_out;
```

One note: I think your `FFT_OUT_SIZE` should be defined as:

```
const int FFT_OUT_SIZE = NX/2 + 1;
```

The `sizeof(fftw_complex)` looks odd in there...I would only expect it if you were using `malloc()` to allocate the raw buffer in C.